# Fire server side event from Datagrid control via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid, postback

I have a Datagrid with a TemplateColumn, which contains a TextBox.
When the user presses Enter with Focus on the TextBox, I want to fire a server side event such as TextChanged.

For this, I run a script on the TextBox, injected in the code behind.

```
txt.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", String.Format("javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)__doPostBack('{0}', '');", txt.ClientID));
```

The script is properly attached to the control but the server side event is never fired. It's defined as:

```
public void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{......}
```

I also tried __doPostBack('{0}', 'TextChanged').

So, the postback is fired but the event is never called.

Any idea on what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this...

you can use the GetPostbackEventReference method of the Page object to register the ASP.NET server control which can create the postback using a client-side callback.

```
Page.GetPostBackEventReference(txt_sssn_dt);
```

Then,  you can use the __dPostBack event to fire the TextChanged event of the date picker control (txt_sssn_dt). This code had been placed inside the date picker JavaScript function, and it would be fired every time the user selects a date from the date picker.

```
__doPostBack("txt_sssn_dt", "TextChanged");
```

It was also necessary to write a simple JavaScript function to handle the situation when the user just wanted to type the date directly into the date picker (txt_sssn_dt). you can  write a JavaScript function called DoPostBack() for this.

```
function DoPostBack()
{
   __doPostBack("txt_sssn_dt", "TextChanged");
}
```

you have to  call this function on the OnChange event of the date picker control.

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    /...Implementation.../ 
     /.................../
    txt_sssn_dt.Attributes.Add("OnChange", 
          "javascript:return DoPostBack()")
}
```

Taken From here :[JavaScriptAndServerEvents](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JavaScriptAndServerEvents.aspx)

Comment: This didn't work, in my scenario, but I managed to make it work in another way. Thank you for the help.